# How to override a Class from the Angular framework?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to find a way to override an Angular TS class, or at least be able to step through the code in debug mode.
So I would like for example to add : debugger;  or some console.log() to better understand its behavior.

In java I would just copy the source *.java Class in my projet and I would be sure that this class would be taken in priority, 
but in TypeScript / Angular how can I achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Find the function you want to debug in the `node_modules/@angular` folder in your project folder. You can edit angular's source files there. 
When you want to reset the source to the original just delete the `@angular` folder, and do a `npm install` in the command line.

Comment: well yes, but it is JS transpiled code quite difficult to understand. I would like to override/edit the TypeScript code ....